# I don't understand how this Integration test is failing in Grails

Tags: grails, integration-testing

This is a basic mock of a web service where a Patient object is checked for eligibility. I have included the console output to show the test failing.

When I run this test in the groovyConsole it passes.

Basic Patient Class:

```
class Patient {
    String firstName, lastName
    Date dateOfBirth
}
```

Create the patient object:

```
Patient p1 = new Patient(
    firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith',
    dateOfBirth: new GregorianCalendar(1968, Calendar.AUGUST, 23).time
).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

Mock setup:

This test normally queries a web service.  I need to mock the service due to firewall issues. I build a tree that replicates the service call.

```
def eligibilityMock(Patient pat) {
    def tree = { -> return [:].withDefault{ tree() } }
    def member = tree()

    if (pat.firstName == "Mike" && pat.lastName == "Smith") {
        member.memberInfo.memberDetails.value.memberFirstName.value = 'Mike'
    }
    member
}
```

I call the mocked service

```
//def memberInfo = eligibilityMock(p1)
def member = humanaEligibilityMock(p1).memberInfo
```

I expect the firstName to match

```
assert p1.firstName == memberInfo.memberDetails?.value?.memberFirstName?.value
```

It seem the values match up, however the assertion fails.

```
 p1.firstName == memberInfo.memberDetails?.value?.memberFirstName?.value
    |         |  |          |              |      |                |
    Mike      |  |          |              |      [value:[:]]      [:]
              |  |          |              [memberFirstName:[value:[:]]]
              |  |          [value:[memberFirstName:[value:[:]]]]
              |  [memberInfo:[memberDetails:[value:[memberFirstName:[value:Mike]
              false
```

Comment: pat.firstName == "Mike" && pat.lastName && "Smith" ??? Is it correct? Perhaps it should be pat.lastName == "Smith"?

Comment: Have you tried it without the safe navigation operators (remove the question marks in your assert statement)?

Comment: removing the safe navigation operators had no effect.

Comment: memberInfo == memberInfo:[memberDetails:[value:[memberFirstName:[value:Marcus]

Comment: memberInfo.memberDetails == [:]  why is this happening?  how can i get to the information in this tree?

Comment: Solved:  basically I returned the treeMap from the wrong level

Comment: def member = humanaEligibilityMock(p1).memberInfo